# How to install google protobuf on FreeBSD

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, freebsd, maven-dependency-plugin

I am trying to find a step by step guide to installing  protobuf on FreeBSD..
I tried installing with pkd_add but it does not find it

Comment: This probably shouldn't be posted to stackoverflow...

Answer (score 2):

Use either binary packages - "pkg install protobuf" ("pkg search protobuf" to see what packages are available) - or install from ports; "cd /usr/ports/devel/protobuf && make install".